# Calendar show the date based on displayed date but took it from the day (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make an update page that will update the date inserted by the user. but, when the user clicked on the date, the calendar will displayed month from the day. i already set the date displayed would be 'dd-mm-YY", i dont know if i am explaining this correctly.

here is the image of the datepicker that i used. the date displayed is from the database. 05/02/2018 (dd-mm-YY), when user clicked on the date the month displayed by the calendar should be in february but it is in may, from 05/02/2018.

how can i solve this?

[image: datepicker]

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" >Date Start:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" id="datestart23"  name="datestart" placeholder="Date Start" class="form-control" required value="<? if($_GET['datestart']!=''){ echo $_GET['datestart']; } else{ echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row_date['datestart']));  } ?>" />
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  $('#datestart23').dateTimePicker({
                  format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
                  });
                  </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to be correct. which plugin you are using??

Comment: <!-- DATE PICKER -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date-time-picker.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: i used this from jquery-ui

Comment: There must be some configuration file where you select locale. The date appears to be correct; it's just written in US date format.

Comment: how do i solve this? i tried to search 'locale' inside the js file. but cant find it